# Use ajax to display form data/triggers don't work with invisible panels?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I've got an add product page for users to select a product from the dropdown list, then punch in pertinent data on a form specific to the product selected; after they submit the info, I want to get rid of that form and display the data in a read-only form in it's place. I thought it would be easiest to use 2 update panels for each product; one input form set to visible and a display form set to invisible, and then have buttons on the input forms to insert the data and make the display forms visible. Unfortunately, (especially after having spent some time coding it) I just found out that trigger events WON'T WORK ON INVISIBLE PANELS!!! Is there a way around this? What can I do? This is my first go-round with programming, btw, so the simpler the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only one `UpdatePanel` (always visible) - have two regular ASP.NET panels - one for input and  other for display and control visibility of these panels.

Whenever, you make any server side control as invisible, the relevant markup (html + js) does not get sent to browser side so the functionality (such as AJAX) that relies on browser side elements (html + js) does not work.

Comment: Why is that? Is there a smarter way to display this?

Comment: @Brazos, what r u referring to when u say "why is that?". Invisible control's markup is not send to browser to reduce the response size.